# Does Haskell support debug?

Tags: debugging, haskell, functional-programming

For example this is a function:

```
iffthen :: [String] -> Parser String
iffthen a = do 
x <- symbol (head a)
               y <- booleana (head (tail a))
               z <- symbol (head (tail (tail a)))
               k <- assignP (head (tail (tail (tail a))))
               l <- symbol (head (tail (tail (tail (tail a)))))
               m <- assignP (head (tail (tail (tail (tail (tail a))))))
               return k
```

I need to see what really do every instructions

Comment: You have `Debug.Trace`, but since Haskell is a *lazy* language, it is usually harder to get a good trace: a lot of parts are not evaluated, or much later in the process.

Comment: About your code, I would really advice to use pattern matching here.

Comment: Thanks Willem Van Onsem

Comment: Note that, if the `[String]` argument is meant to be the sequence of tokens to be parsed, the code above (or any equivalent variant using pattern matching) looks quite wrong to me. If it is meant to be something else, the approach might be correct (but it still looks weird -- what are those strings in the list?).

Comment: Standard haskell only supports `bug` and `rebug`. If you want `debug`, you have to upgrade to [Haskell Prime](https://prime.haskell.org/).

Comment: More seriously.... Others have already suggested some changes to the structure of your program. Probably the most important technique for debugging Haskell programs (or, really, any programs) is to simplify and clarify your code and break it up into the smallest *meaningful* pieces you can. Small pieces of code are much easier to test, and the easier your code is to understand the better your chances are of finding the problem. Yes, debugging tools are important, but you have to get your code into decent shape before you can really use them efficiently.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [**`trace :: String -> a -> a`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Debug-Trace.html#v:trace) of the `Debug.Trace`, or related functions like [**`traceShowId :: Show a => a -> a`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Debug-Trace.html#v:traceShowId). This function basically prints the attached `String` parameter in case the function is evaluated, and returns the result of the function.

We can thus - for some content that *can* be printed - attach such `trace` functions, and thus print information. Note that debugging in Haskell is typically different from debugging in imperative languages, mainly due to laziness: usually functions are not evaluated, unless we need the result. So that means that some functions will never get evaluated, or these are evaluated long after we constructed that function.

Abut your function, I would advice to use *pattern matching* here, and remove the noise of unused variables:

```
iffthen :: [String] -> Parser String
iffthen (ifs : cond : thens : val1 : elses : val2 : _) = do 
    symbol ifs
    booleana cond
    symbol thens
    k <- assignP val1
    symbol elses
    assignP val2
    return k
```

(Given I interpreted what you want correnctly, and `ifs`, `thens`, `elses` are symbols, `cond` is the condition, and `val1` and `val2` are the values of the `if`-`then`-`else` expression).

It is probably even better not to use a list (since the number of elements is *not* guaranteed at compile time), and thus construct a sperate type with specific parameters.

Comment: I'd go even farther than "switch from list indexing to pattern matching": these strings should be passed in a record, with descriptive names for each argument.

Comment: Yes, but I could not immediately find the functions. I assume that `a1` is if_symbol, then the condition, etc.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to `trace`, check out `traceM :: Applicative f => String -> f ()` and `traceShowM :: (Show a, Applicative f) => a -> f ()`.

These are handy replacements of `putStrLn` and `print` available in any monad context:

```
iffthen :: [String] -> Parser String
iffthen a = do 
x <- symbol (head a)
               traceM "booleana"
               y <- booleana (head (tail a))
               traceM "symbol 1"
               z <- symbol (head (tail (tail a)))
               traceM "assignP 1"
               k <- assignP (head (tail (tail (tail a))))
               traceM "symbol 2"
               l <- symbol (head (tail (tail (tail (tail a)))))
               traceM "assignP 2"
               m <- assignP (head (tail (tail (tail (tail (tail a))))))
               return k
```

If you're interested in each parser's result, use `traceShowId` with `<$>` etc.

```
iffthen :: [String] -> Parser String
iffthen a = do 
x <- symbol (head a)
               y <- traceShowId <$> booleana (head (tail a))
               z <- traceShowId <$> symbol (head (tail (tail a)))
               k <- traceShowId <$> assignP (head (tail (tail (tail a))))
               l <- traceShowId <$> symbol (head (tail (tail (tail (tail a)))))
               m <- traceShowId <$> assignP (head (tail (tail (tail (tail (tail a))))))
               return k
```

Comment: The thing about `trace` is you need to be *very* aware of exactly how laziness works. For example, try `(traceM "never prints" *> pure ()) ()`; and in your second example, the traces for `x`, `y`, `z`, `l`, and `m` are almost guaranteed not to fire unless `Parser` does something very unusual in its `(>>=)` implementation, like call `seq` or `evaluate` or use bang patterns.

Comment: Another gotcha with "traceM" is that if you give it a constant string it will only be printed once. After that the compiler figures that it knows what the expression evaluates to, and it won't evaluate it again.

Answer (score 0):

`ghci` does [have a stepping debugger](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.4.1/docs/html/users_guide/ghci-debugger.html). Since Haskell code tends to be functional and lazy, I think it is going to lead to surprises sometimes. Emacs `haskell-mode` used to have [debugger integration](https://web.archive.org/web/20140326092158/http://chrisdone.com/posts/ghci-debugger)... I think I came across a comment by the author of that integration stating that the debugger is problematic in some way, but I can't find it now. But I've tried the debugger on some basic examples, and it works as advertised.